# How do I learn literature and grammar of English, Farsi and Japanese and become fluent?

Tags: english, grammar, japanese, persian, literature

I'm planning to become a translator and I can already understand, read and write Farsi and English and don't know Japanese.
for Japanese, I'm Studying Genki volumes and Japanese from zero books, I've also purchased these books as well for later:

`Japanese Short Stories for Beginners: 20 Captivating Short Stories to Learn Japanese & Grow Your Vocabulary the Fun Way!`

`A dictionary of basic Japanese grammar by Seiichi Makino`

when though I can understand talk everyday general Farsi and English I have no idea how their grammar works and if somebody talks or writes something in pure literature and use harder sentences and grammar, I'm doomed.

after these three languages, I have French and Italian and Spanish and German and Korean and Chinese on my calendar for the next decade. but that's a discussion for tomorrow. so I don't I'll bring it up for the next couple of years.

The problem at hand: my low level of intellect when it comes to English and farsi in terms of grammar and low amount of learned words dictionary in my memory.

I seek a dictionary of 10,000 words for each language.

and I've yet to start Japanese, I use `Yomiwa` Android app to learn the order of strokes but I wouldn't mind learning it from a book instead plus I'll also need to ace the Japanese Grammar and let's not forget the necessary words I need to learn at the start.

In the end what I'm actually asking is which books, documents, and applications I should spend my time and money on, so I can become fluent in all three, especially when comes down to pure literature and also Grammar.

my native language is Farsi. and I can read books in Faris/English language.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Please be aware that the rules on Stack Exchange are different from those on forums and social media. For example, questions shouldn't be too broad. Could you please take the [tour] for some basic info about Stack Exchange and read [How do I avoid asking questions that are too broad?](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/638/800) for advice in breaking down your question into smaller ones?

Comment: how about this "learning English grammar, literature and words" + "learning Farsi grammar, literature and words" + "learning Japanese grammar, literature and words" in three posts. I'll wait for your answer, if you agree I'll edit this post and add two more.
thanx

Comment: That would be better, although without seeing what the actual questions would look like, it still seems very broad. If you asked, "I'm looking for a dictionary for language A that meets criteria X, Y and Z" or "I'm looking for series of language learning books for language A that meets criteria X, Y and Z", that would be fine. But something like "How do I learn literature, grammar and vocabulary for language A" would still be too broad.